# Can't save data Realm Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm new in Realm database. I want to save data to the Realm, but can't save even though the data I entered doesn't yet exist.

Example :

First, I input data OA as afdeling, 001 as Blok, 01 as Group Sample, and 1 as Pokok ke. Saved successfully.

Second, I input data OA as afdeling, 001 as Blok, 01 as Group Sample, and 2 as Pokok ke. Saved successfully.

Third, I input data OB as afdeling, 002 as Blok, 01 as Group Sample, and 2 as Pokok ke. Failed to save data. Toast appear "Data is already exist". Even though the data I entered doesn't yet exist.

This is code for check is data already exist :

```
public <E extends RealmModel> boolean isParentIdExist(Class<E> eClass, String value) {
    E data = mRealm.where(eClass).equalTo("parent_id", value).findFirst();
    return data != null;
}

public <E extends RealmModel> boolean isPokokExist(Class<E> eClass, String value) {
    E data = mRealm.where(eClass).equalTo("pokok_ke", value).findFirst();
    return data != null;
}

public <E extends RealmModel> boolean isAfdelingExist(Class<E> eClass, String value) {
    E data = mRealm.where(eClass).equalTo("afdeling", value).findFirst();
    return data != null;
}

public <E extends RealmModel> boolean isBlokExist(Class<E> eClass, String value) {
    E data = mRealm.where(eClass).equalTo("blok", value).findFirst();
    return data != null;
}

public <E extends RealmModel> boolean isGroupSampleExist(Class<E> eClass, String value) {
    E data = mRealm.where(eClass).equalTo("group_sample", value).findFirst();
    return data != null;
}
```

and This is code for save data :

```
if (isParentIdExist(ModelAddTransaction.class, parent_id)) {
    if (isAfdelingExist(ModelAddTransaction.class, afdeling) && isBlokExist(ModelAddTransaction.class, blok) && isGroupSampleExist(ModelAddTransaction.class, group_sample) && isPokokExist(ModelAddTransaction.class, pokok_ke)) {
        Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, "Data is already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        tambahData();
        Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, "Data added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent moveViewMaster = new Intent(AddTransaction.this, ViewResult.class);
        startActivity(moveViewMaster);
   }
} else {
      tambahData();
      Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, "Data added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Intent moveViewMaster = new Intent(AddTransaction.this, ViewResult.class);
      startActivity(moveViewMaster);
}
```

and This is ModelAddTransaction :

```
class ModelAddTransaction extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String parent_id;
    private String date;
    private String afdeling;
    private String pokok_ke;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up your project and use this code to inset data.

```
 public void saveData() {

    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Number id = realm.where(AddToCartRealmModel.class).max("productID");
            int key = (id == null) ? 1 : id.intValue() + 1;
            AddToCartRealmModel addToCartModel = realm.createObject(AddToCartRealmModel.class, key);

            try {
                if (packageModel != null) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    addToCartModel.setPackageName(packageModel.getServiceName());
                    addToCartModel.setProductPrice(packageModel.getPrice());
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(addToCartModel);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                if(realm!=null){
                    realm.close();
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```